# set to localStorage from a server side language

Tags: go, local-storage

If it's possible to set a cookie from a server side language, is it possible for a server side language to store data in the localStorage property of a browser? I'm interested in doing it in Go but I suppose the principle would be the same in any language. Go has a `SetCookie`  to set a Cookie but not a function to set localStorage. Is there a way to implement it?

```
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
```

Comment: No. Cookies are transported in the HTTP header, local storage stuff happens on the browser via JavaScript only so you'll have to send HTML with JavaScript code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Could you give some more context so that we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: @Kos I wish to store some information in the browser that's too big for a cookie. I thought if Go could set a cookie (i.e. reach the browser), there must be a way for Go to store more information via local storage. The function with the information I wish to store doesn't otherwise return to the browser (i.e. as part of an http request)

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Can you please accept my answer if you fill it answers your question? The answer has got upvotes from many users.

Answer (score 14):

`localStorate` is meant for reading/writing on the client side only. It's not possible to set it from the server side code as you do with cookies using `Set-Cookie` response header. More information on [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).